# Bend Modifier Cage

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to see the cage (or whatever it is called) that is being used by the bend modifier?

At the moment I do not see anything and seeing where the deformer is being applied would be very helpful

In the image I have a red rectangle where the bend is approximately being applied.

[image]

thank you

Comment: I don't think there is, have you applied your scale and rotations though? If you don't, the bend modifier might behave not as expected.

Comment: Thank you I will apply the transforms

Comment: There are the Mesh Deform and Lattice Modifiers that will give you the visibility and control you need, but are quite a bit more complicated to use than the Bend Modifier.

Comment: Thanks I will look into them